# How could I speed up this Rcpp code?

Tags: r, rcpp

I had implemented a function in R which was long to run. I have succeeded in improving it in R but now I would like to speed it up more by using Rcpp package.

I have created the following Rcpp code. Unfortunately, it takes approximately the same time to run as the R code. I would like thus to improve it. Has anyone an idea on how to improve this piece of code?

Thanks a lot!

```
#include <math.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
double kernelcpp(NumericVector a, NumericVector b, int N){
  int i;
  double sum=0.0;
  for (i=0;i<N;i++){
    if (a[i] > b[i])
      sum+= a[i] - b[i];
    else
      sum+= b[i] - a[i];
  }
  return(exp( - sum));
}
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector testFromontcpp(NumericMatrix z1, NumericMatrix z2, int Nbootstrap){
  // first element of TKeps = TK
  int i,j,k,t;
  int dim1 = z1.nrow();
  int dim2 = z2.nrow();
  double n1 = (double) dim1;
  double n2 = (double) dim2;
  int dimension = z1.ncol();
  int N = dim1 + dim2;
  NumericVector TKeps(Nbootstrap+1);
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix bb(N,N);

  double cc = 1 / (n1*n2*(n1+n2-2));
  double a = sqrt(1/(n1*n1-n1)-cc);
  double b = - sqrt(1/(n2*n2-n2)-cc);

  for (i=0 ; i<N ; i++){
    for (j=0 ; j<N ; j++){
    if (i != j){
      if (i < dim1) {
        if (j < dim1){
          bb(i,j) = kernelcpp(z1(i,_),z1(j,_),dimension);
        } else {
          bb(i,j) = kernelcpp(z1(i,_),z2(j-dim1,_),dimension);
        }
      }
      else{
        if (j < dim1){
          bb(i,j) = kernelcpp(z2(i-dim1,_),z1(j,_),dimension);
        } else {
          bb(i,j) = kernelcpp(z2(i-dim1,_),z2(j-dim1,_),dimension);
        }
      }
    }
    }
  }

  TKeps(0)=0.0;
  for (i=0 ; i<N ; i++){
    for (j=0 ; j<N ; j++){
    if (i != j){
      if (i < dim1) {
        if (j < dim1){
          TKeps(0) += bb(i,j)* (a*a + cc);
        } else {
          TKeps(0) += bb(i,j) * (a*b + cc);
        }
      }
      else{
        if (j < dim1){
          TKeps(0) += bb(i,j) * (a*b + cc);
        } else {
          TKeps(0) += bb(i,j) * (b*b + cc);
        }
      }
    }
    }
  }


  for (k=1 ; k<=Nbootstrap ; k++){
    TKeps(k)=0;
    int R[N];
    for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
      R[i] = i;
    for (i = 0; i < N - 1 ; i++) {
      int j = i + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (N - i) + 1);
      t = R[j];
      R[j] = R[i];
      R[i] = t;
    }

    for (i=0 ; i<N ; i++){
      for (j=0 ; j<N ; j++){
        if (i != j){ 
          if (R[i] < n1) {
            if (R[j] < n1){
              TKeps(k) += bb(i,j) * (a*a + cc);
            } else {
              TKeps(k) += bb(i,j) * (a*b + cc);
            }
          } else{
            if (R[j] < n1){
              TKeps(k) += bb(i,j) * (b*a + cc);
            } else {
              TKeps(k) += bb(i,j) * (b*b + cc);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return(TKeps);
}
```

Comment: You could define `kernelcpp` as an inline function since it is called so many times. I don't know how big a difference it will make, but it is easy to try and see. In general, function calls are slow compared to executing statements in place.

Comment: Profile the code first, to see which line(s) take up the most time. Then you'll know what part to improve.

Comment: It is possible to do profiling on Rcpp functions?

Comment: Of course it is possibly to profile Rcpp code just how it *is possible to profile any other C++ code*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I do not exactly know what your code does, I can see two things from the scratch:

- The function you call from your R environment is testFromontcpp(...). I suggest that this function should have SEXP values as parameters. Those S-Expressions are pointer to the memory of R. If you don't use SEXP, then both matrices will be copied:
  Consider a 1000x1000 matrix, this means you have 1 million entries saved in R, which are copied to C++. To do so write:

  testFromontcpp(SEXP x, SEXP y, SEXP z) {

  NumericMatrix z1(x), z2(y);

  int *Nbootstrap = INTEGER(z);

  ...
  }

Be careful: In the for-loop you cannot use `i<Nbootstrap`. You have to write `i<*Nbootstrap`!!!

- Secondly...and more important: Since R's matrices are saved as pointer to column and from the column pointer to the row, C's matrices are saved the other way round. What I want to say is that it costs a lot to jump into memory and jump back the whole time instead of following the memory path. My suggestion for this is: Switch the for-loops, so first iterate over the row of a specific column and not the other way round.

To the last point: In a task at university I had the problem with iterating over matrices, too. In my case it was way cheaper to transpose the matrix and then do calculations.

I hope I could help you.

Best,
Michael

PS: Referring to point 1...I just benchmarked your code with your implementation and with using SEXP. With SEXP it is slightly quicker for a 100x100 matrix with random numbers between 1 to 10.

Comment: Thank you!  With your advices, my code run time is now divided by two :)

Comment: You are welcome! I'm happy I could help you. :) Maybe I find some more time to take a closer look to the code. By the way: When passing the rows/cols of a matrix to a function, all elements are copied, too - every time. Maybe it helps to "wrap" those rows/cols as vectors and then passing the reference of the vector (like a pointer).

Comment: Yes, I was trying to do that ;)