# Error in inline

Tags: r, inline, rcpp

```
require(inline)
require(Rcpp)

sig <- signature(a="NumericVector", b="NumericVector", N="int")
body <- 'int i=0;
  double somme=0.0;
  for (i=0;i < N ;i++){
    if (a[i] > b[i])
      somme += a[i] - b[i];
    else
      somme += b[i] - a[i];
  }
  return(exp( - somme));'
f <- cxxfunction(sig, body, plugin="Rcpp", includes = c('#include <math.h>'))
```

I have used the following code. But it yields me an error I do not understand:

```
file11346d634c82.cpp: In function 'SEXPREC* file11346d634c82(SEXP, SEXP, SEXP)':
file11346d634c82.cpp:32:16: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
file11346d634c82.cpp:33:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct SEXPREC'
C:/Users/sn235843/DOCUME~1/R/R-31~1.0/include/Rinternals.h:424:16: error: forward declaration of 'struct SEXPREC'
file11346d634c82.cpp:33:19: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct SEXPREC'
```

The line 33 is the `or (i=0;i < N ;i++){`. I have read the `cxxfunction` help and tried to change this line 33 to

```
for (i=0;i < as<int>(N) ;i++){
```

and even:

```
for (i=0;i < INTEGER(N) ;i++){
```

However, I still get errors...

Where does this error come from? What does it mean?

**Remark:** this question is related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781428/how-could-i-speed-up-this-rcpp-code)

Answer (score 2):

You are using the inline package and its cxxfunction incorrectly. It will **not** know how to make `N` an `int`.

Use Rcpp Attributes by reading the vignette that ships with the package, and convert to using Attributes. It is more concise and simpler.  It also provides the converters you desire here, but do not get as you use the older interface.

*Edit:*

Below is a complete file you can simply pull in via `sourceCpp("nameOfTheFile.cpp")` and it will compile, link, load and run the code (including the R portion). I changed it return somme directly.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double foo(NumericVector a, NumericVector b) {
  int N = a.size();
  double somme=0.0;
  for (int i=0;i < N; i++){
    if (a[i] > b[i])
      somme += a[i] - b[i];
    else
      somme += b[i] - a[i];
  }
  return somme;
}

/*** R
set.seed(42)
a <- rnorm(1000)
b <- rnorm(1000)
foo(a,b)
*/
```

Demo:

```
R> sourceCpp("foo.cpp")

R> set.seed(42)

R> a <- rnorm(1000)

R> b <- rnorm(1000)

R> foo(a,b)
[1] 1123.49
R>
```

Comment: Yes, I know this way to code my function. But someone advised me to use `inline` package to gain speed. I wanted to try to use it.

Comment: Sure you are free to use it -- but if you do study the (numerous) examples to understand what you did wrong. But it won't be faster than Attributes.