# How to declare input into Rcpp functions?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am an absolute `Rcpp`-beginner, so please be warned that a beginner's question is about to come.

Consider this example:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix mat_1(NumericMatrix X){
 do.stuff.with.X
}
```

My understanding is that this defines a function `mat_1` in the workspace of R that takes a numeric matrix as an input and returns a numeric matrix in the end. However, [looking e.g. here](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.armadillo.html) I understand that I can also define

```
SEXP mat_2(SEXP X){
Rcpp::NumericMatrix x(X);                 
 do.stuff.with.x
}
```

or alternatively

```
SEXP mat_3(SEXP X){
NumericMatrix x(as<NumericMatrix>(X))
 do.stuff.with.x
}
```

My understanding is that this defines the output of the function as an S-expression, and it requires an S-expression as an input, which is internally converted (?) to a numeric matrix.

Now, [looking at this document](http://people.math.aau.dk/~sorenh/teaching/2014-Rcpp/doc/computing-notes.pdf), which has been a very valuable resource to me, I learn that I can also write

```
NumericMatrix mat_4( NumericMatrix X&){
 do.stuff.with.X
}
```

Here, my understanding is that instead of making a copy of `X`, the `Rcpp`-function uses a reference to the  `R` object. I am actually not sure I understand what this means. Wasn't the point of using `SEXP` that no copy is made, or did I get something wrong? Also, if it saves memory and is thus more efficient, why would I ever use something else?

I am sure I missed some options. Anyway, **my big question is this:** from the point of view of the `R` user (me), I call each function `mat_1, mat_2, mat_3` or `mat_4` supplying a numeric matrix (which is an R object in my workspace, and hence an `SEXP`), and it seems I should get the same output (a numeric matrix, which will be a `SEXP` anyway from `R`'s perspective, right?). I would appreciate some guidance as to the relative merits of these seemingly identical ways to define a function. That is, assuming we know exactly what the function input will be and what the output will be,

1. Why and when does it pay off to use `NumericMatrix` instead of `SEXP` for the argument, or vice versa?
2. Why and when to use `&`?
3. If I know the function will return a numeric matrix, are there reasons to declare the function as a `SEXP`? Are there reasons to stick to `NumericMatrix`?

Or am I completely missing the point?

Furthermore, is there any practial difference between the conversion used in `mat_2` and `mat_3`? That is, are there differences between `Rcpp::NumericMatrix x(X)` and `NumericMatrix x(as<NumericMatrix>(X))`?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: You are asking several questions here which co-mingle generic questions about C++ with specifics about Rcpp.  SO has a lot of great resources about the former; we ship eight vignettes with the latter, and then there is also the [book on Rcpp](http://www.rcpp.org/book).

Comment: I agree. One problem that I have is that I can't easily distinguish between Rcpp and C++ specifics since I only know C++ through Rcpp, but I realize that this is a problem when asking a question.

Comment: I am aware of the vignettes and the book. They are tremendous resources and the examples in there helped me a big deal to get started, but I feel that they, the book in particular, require a lot of background knowledge which makes it difficult to read up on a particular topic. This is problematic if you don't really know what you are looking for, which I think is a typical beginner's problem. However, if you could point me to the particular vignette where I find answers to the above (maybe even a particular section or keyword I should be looking for) I would appreciate this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright. Trying to give some clues. First of all, if you are a beginner, you got it right with the first function, use `mat_1`. As your skills improve, you might understand some of the differences between `mat_1` and the other one, and eventually move to ... use `mat_1`, because that's the one you want to use.

1. Always. Most users should not use `SEXP`, ever.
2. It does not make a difference in this case. Rcpp will know what to do with the reference, but what happens is pretty much the same, it creates an object locally somewhere and gives you a reference to it. The distinction between pass by value and by reference makes a difference if you were to call if you were to call `mat_4` from another C++ function.
3. If you know the type, use the type. That's the whole point of Rcpp. `SEXP` is R's catch all type, if you return a `SEXP` it can be anything, if you return a `NumericMatrix` you know by design that you return a numeric matrix, huge advantage and pretty much the whole reason Rcpp exists.

I let you decide if you were missing the point.

In general `as<>` will tend to try harder, but it does not make a difference in that case.

In short: use `mat_1`. There's lots of other stuff to learn, don't concern yourself with this yet.

Comment: Thanks Romain! I appreciate your feedback. Just a very quick follow up to my question: 1. [based on this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781428/how-could-i-speed-up-this-rcpp-code/24782888#24782888), I understand that using `SEXP` for the function arguments avoids copies in memory. If I have very large matrices, say, should I thus prefer using a `SEXP`? 2. To your point 2, if I were to use the output of `mat_4` in another `C++` function (which I will), would I prefer using `&`?

Comment: There is no additional memory in a NumericMatrix beyond the SEXP, none, zero. irrespective of how big the matrix is. You don't pay for a NumericMatrix. You however get something convenient to use. For 2, not really, passing the matrix by value is cheap, as again the data is not copied, only a pointer. I cannot say much more given the code example `do.stuff.with.X`. For Rcpp types like NumericMatrix, just pass them by value.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks Romain for taking your time to help me out here. I do appreciate this!